# Consultar base de datos y mostrar mensaje ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo un formulario en donde se guarda informacion en una tabla de base de datos, pero antes de que la info se guarde necesito que se haga una consulta a la tabla por las columnas (Codigo y Codigo_fac) para comprobar que el registro no exista ya, y si ya existe no debe guardar el registro y debera mostrar un mensaje diciendo que el registro ya existe.

```html
 public partial class MyModel
 {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Codigo { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Codigo_fac { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Fecha { get; set; }
    }
```

MyController

```html
public ActionResult Solicitud(MyModel model)
{
try
   {
   tbl.Codigo = model.Codigo;
   tbl.Codigo_fac = model.Codigo_fac;
   tbl.Nombre = model.Nombre;
   tbl.fecha = model.fecha;
   bd.ProdMuestreo.Add(tbl);           
   bd.SaveChanges();
   TempData["sms"] = "Solicitud realizada con éxito";
   ViewBag.sms = TempData["sms"].ToString();
}
  catch (Exception e)
  {
  TempData["error"] = e.ToString();
  ViewBag.error = TempData["error"].ToString();
  }
return View();
}
```

Comment: Básicamente quieres este If: Registro Existe ? "Sí, lanzar mensaje de error" :  "No, procedemos a insertar"

Comment: asi es @fredyfx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero lo primero: La documentación oficial

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.8

**FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable)**

> Devuelve el primer elemento de una secuencia o un valor predeterminado si la secuencia no contiene elementos.

Antes de seguir, en LinQ hay un par de métodos que tienden a confudirse: `SingleOrDefault` y `FirstOrDefault`, así que para evitar futuros contratiempos, aquí lo siguiente:

Si el resultado esperado retorna 0 registros:

```
SingleOrDefault retorna el valor por defecto de ese tipo (ej. el valor by default de int es 0)
FirstOrDefault retorna el valor por defecto de ese tipo
```

Si el resultado esperado retorna 1 registros:

```
SingleOrDefault retorna ese registro
FirstOrDefault retorna ese registro
```

Si el resultado esperado retorna muchos registros:

```
SingleOrDefault lanza una excepción
FirstOrDefault returna el 1 registro
```

**Conclusión:**

Si deseas que se lance una excepción si el resultados contiene muchos registros, utiliza `SingleOrDefault`.

Si siempre quieres 1 registro sin importar lo que contenga el resultado, usa `FirstOrDefault`.

Esta información previa fue extraída y traducida de : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4760190/3613462

Ahora, con respecto al código, aquí tienes:

```
public ActionResult Solicitud(MyModel model)
{
    try
    {
        var modeloExistente = bd.Plan.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Codigo == model.Codigo && m.Codigo_fac == model.Codigo_fac.value);

        if (modeloExistente == null) {
            tbl.Codigo = model.Codigo;
            tbl.Codigo_fac = model.Codigo_fac;
            tbl.Nombre = model.Nombre;
            tbl.fecha = model.fecha;
            bd.ProdMuestreo.Add(tbl);
            bd.SaveChanges();
            TempData["sms"] = "Solicitud realizada con éxito";
            ViewBag.sms = TempData["sms"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.sms = "mostrar un mensaje diciendo que el registro ya existe.";
        }


    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        TempData["error"] = e.ToString();
        ViewBag.error = TempData["error"].ToString();
    }
    return View();
}
```