# La secuencia no contiene elementos LinQ

Tags: c#, linq, soap, wcf

Me encuentro con un problema en mi **Web Services**.

Actualmente estoy consumiendo un servicio y luego generando una consulta con `LinQ`, el detalle es que al momento de hacerla, me da el error mencionado.

En la linea de proveedores `prove = entities.proveedores.where`.... acá me da error de:

> que no contiene elementos

si le agrego el `FirstOfDefault()`, me da error de:

> ForeKey Duplicate

si hago la validación de `proveedores.pro_codigo == 0`, al momento de ejecutar el siguiente bloque de código: `solicitud.prove.codi` y los siguientes me da error de:

> exception null

¿que creen que podría ser? ¿está mal hecha la consulta a la **BD**?

Dejo mi **Código**:

```
ServiceReferenceActATCProveedor.ZMMF_UPD_PROV_ATC_MAX_APPResponse response = client.ZMMF_UPD_PROV_ATC_MAX_APP(upd_atc);
response.ET_UPD_ATC_PROV.Where(res => res.RESUL == "X").ToList().ForEach(res =>
{
    proveedores prove = entities.proveedores.Where(obj => obj.pro_codigosap == res.LIFNR).First();
    if (prove== null)
    {
        proveedores proveedores = new proveedores();
        proveedores.pro_codigosap = res.LIFNR;
        proveedores.pro_nombre = res.NAME1;
        proveedores.pro_correo1 = res.EMAIL1;
        proveedores.pro_correo2 = res.EMAIL2;
        proveedores.pro_usuario = res.STCD1;
        proveedores.pro_clave = res.STCD1;
        proveedores.pro_tipo = true;
        proveedores.pro_cambiarclave = true;

        prove = entities.proveedores.Add(proveedores);
        entities.SaveChanges();
    }

    string ORDTRB = res.ORDTRB.TrimStart('0');
    atc solicitud = entities.atc.Where(obj => (obj.atc_otnum == ORDTRB && obj.atc_ot_tareaotnum == res.POSIOT)).First();
    solicitud.atc_tieneprove = true;
    solicitud.atc_provecodi = prove.pro_codigo;
    solicitud.atc_provecodisap = prove.pro_codigosap;
    solicitud.atc_provenom = prove.pro_nombre;
    solicitud.atc_provecorreo1 = prove.pro_correo1;
    solicitud.atc_provecorreo2 = prove.pro_correo2;
    solicitud.atc_provetipo = true;

    entities.atc.Attach(solicitud);
    entities.Entry(solicitud).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
    entities.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: de donde sale la variable `entities` ?

Comment: ¿Debería permitir la base de datos tener datos repetidos con la misma llave foránea? Me refiero a este código: `proveedores prove = entities.proveedores.Where(obj => obj.pro_codigosap == res.LIFNR);` Nótese que está sin el `.First();`

Comment: la tengo inicializada al inicio del método post : db_ss_atcEntities entities = new db_ss_atcEntities();

Comment: @fredyfx no, no debería de permitir eso, no tengo acceso a la BD, me mandaron hacerle modificaciones a éste webApi.

Comment: en ese caso, realiza consultas SQL para ver todos los valores que hay con el pro_codigosap sea igual al res.LIFNR, si es más de 1 registro duplicado, habla con el que desarrolló la inserción, está permitiendo duplicados según lo que dices. Por otro lado, esta respuesta te ayudará: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/289185/822

Comment: @fredyfx gracias, ahora me quedo más claro el concepto de FirstOrDefault(), lo que se me ocurre de momento es eliminar los registros de esa tabla y volver a ejecutar el código.

Comment: ¡Dale hermano¡, ¡tú puedes¡, a elevar ese cosmos y desarrollar con todo el power 2.0!!!